# Update panel in different places

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

My update panel must update some panel out of content of this panel, for example I've got

```
<update panel>
        some staff
</update panel>
<div>
        No need to update staff
        Need to update staff
</div>
```

How can I update "Need to update staff" when updating "some staff" in my update panel ?

Comment: The short/simple answer is you'll need two UpdatePanel's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd either:

- Have them both in the same updatePanel
- Have them in two seperate updatePanels with an [update trigger](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

As you say they have to be seperate (why?) use the second option.

Comment: @nCdy - Thanks for the accept, out of interest which option did you go for?

Answer (score 0):

The simples must be to expand your update panel.

Otherwise put your div in a partial page and load with jquerys load method.